# How to use WordNet in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin, jaws-wordnet

I am trying to use WordNet in GAE but I am getting the error mentioned below. I am able to access the WordNet after specifying the directory with the help of appengine properties. Not sure if GAE allows the kind of reading WordNet does to read its files. The whole exception trace is there where the last line is my function calling WordNet synset API. The program works fine when executed locally on my machine as web application. So there is nothing wrong with my logic. The problem only occurs when I try to deploy the code to the GAE. At the moment I am trying to access the synsets API made available by WordNet jar.

```
com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (68486dfc867c528f) started at 2015/03/13 06:49:06.494 UTC and was still executing at 2015/03/13 06:50:06.280 UTC.
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.read(RandomAccessFile.java:348)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.RandomAccessReader.readNextCharacter(RandomAccessReader.java:139)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.RandomAccessReader.readToNextEndOfLine(RandomAccessReader.java:114)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.LineLocator.getLine(LineLocator.java:115)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.MultipleLineLocator.getLines(MultipleLineLocator.java:93)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.MultipleLineLocator.getLines(MultipleLineLocator.java:71)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.file.SenseIndexReader.getAllEntries(SenseIndexReader.java:171)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.file.SenseIndexReader.getLemmaEntries(SenseIndexReader.java:150)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.file.WordFormLookup.loadSynsets(WordFormLookup.java:274)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.file.WordFormLookup.getSynsets(WordFormLookup.java:230)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.file.WordFormLookup.getSynsets(WordFormLookup.java:172)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.impl.file.FileDatabase.getSynsets(FileDatabase.java:87)
    at edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.WordNetDatabase.getSynsets(WordNetDatabase.java:81)
    at com.clusterReviews.myFile.myFunction(myFile.java:346)
```

Comment: It takes too long time to read file on GAE (limited to 60 seconds). Remember that GAE much slower that your local machine, it's just 600Mhz with 128Mb of memory. You could try to call this code through task queue, it have 10 minutes limit

Comment: Thanks Igor. The problem was my processing time itself was more than 1 minute. No issues with file reading at all. The file reads took place for multiple words. It is just that after 1 minutes the GAE gave an exception as the number of times (in my case more than 100 words) it had to read file exceeded the time limit.

Comment: ah, I see, then you definitely should try Task Queue